# Experimental measurement of the difference of momenta of a photon

Tags: photons, experimental-physics, momentum

I am trying to understand how one can measure the difference of momenta $p_x - p_y $ or the sum $p_x + p_y$ of a photon where each of the quantities represents the momenta in each direction. What I want to know is if there exists an apparatus that measures the sum or difference without measuring the momenta in each direction separately and adding them together. In other words, it just measure the sum or difference of momenta in each direction.

Comment: You mean measuring the magnitude and direction?

Comment: Not the direction but the sum or difference of the magnitudes along each direction. Also, not the measuring along each direction separately and the summing it up. Some sort of apparatus or experiment that measures the sum or difference directly.

Comment: If you know the magnitude and direction, you can calculate the differences and sums of components. Apart from that, some types of spin-orbit interactions or raman scattering depend on such combinations - you may check in group theory texts.

Answer (score 0):

Particle physics measures gamma rays, which are photons at very high energy.

Since the photon is a zero mass particle , the magnitude of its momentum can be found using the [four vector equations](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/relmom.htm) (third paragraph)

[image: energy photon]

> and by setting rest mass equal to zero and applying the Planck relationship, we get the momentum expression:

[image: momphot]

The detectors measuring the energy of the gamma give also its impact point in the detector , so there is no difficulty of getting the particular values of the momentum  in the (x,y,z) direction.

An example in the simplest particle detector,  the  [bubble chamber](https://hst-archive.web.cern.ch/archiv/HST2005/bubble_chambers/BCwebsite/index.htm)

[image: event] [image: gammaplot]

> The curved lines in this picture are trails of bubbles formed as charged particles force their way through an unstable mixture of neon and hydrogen. They curve in an applied magnetic field, and spiral because they lose energy quickly.

Knowing the magnetic field, the mass of the particles(from the ionisation) and measuring the curvature gives the vector momentum of the particle.

> The highlighted track that curves to the left (red) was produced by an electron while its partner, which turns to the right, was produced by a positron . Together they are referred to as an electron-positron pair that has 'materialized’ from a high energy photon in the electric field of a nucleus. This is often referred to as 'pair-production

Adding the vector momenta of the electron and positron gives, by conservation of momentum , the vector of the momentum of the gamma photon.